# Additional groups for apache user

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, groups, user-permissions

When configuring the user/group that apache runs under, does the process run *only* with permissions of the specified group, or also with those of which the user is a member?

For example, if Apache runs under `apache:apache`, and I do `usermod -aG somegroup apache`, will the Apache processes be able to write to the following file inside my wwwroot?

```
-r--rw-r--  1 someuser   somegroup       18K Sep 11 14:27 somefile.txt
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to restart the Apache process after modifying the group membership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if apache is a member of `somegroup`, it will have access to any of `somegroup`'s directories and files with permissions as assigned to `somegroup`. (This system has pitfalls, though. EG. if your wwwroot is NFS mounted, make sure you're not squashing any user IDs.)